# PHP RegEx to prevent repeating characters

Tags: php, regex

```
if(preg_match("%(?=.{8})[A-Za-z0-9]([.-]{0,1})%", stripslashes(trim($_POST['username']))))
```

I want the username to be at least 8 characters A-Za-z0-9 with only 1 . or 1 - . How do I implement this? My code is allowing a username of ".............." as valid. <- Don't want that.

BTW: the "." or "-" is meant to be optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, regular expressions just aren't the right tool for the job.

```
$username = stripslashes(trim($_POST['username']));

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{8,}$/', $username)
&& substr_count($username, '-') <= 1
&& substr_count($username, '.') <= 1) {
    # It's valid.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick patch would be to count those characters after the first check.

i.e.,

```
 if (strlen(preg_replace("#[^.-]#", '', $username)) > 2)
     // Not valid.
```

This is not the check you asked for, this counts .'s and -'s together, so two dots or two dashes would be considered valid. But it's quick and easily extended to more characters.

Comment: Ty for your response however minitech's solution worked for me.

Comment: Good! But I was going to suggest a change -- maybe "/[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9.-]{7,}/" would do better, because I don't think you would like usernames like ".htaccess" :-).

Comment: I guess I can make that change. Just curious though how would a username such as ".htaccess" be malicious? Meaning would it be a threat to my security in anyway by allowing a person to have this username? Ty for your input btw

Comment: btw the correct code to prevent a username like .htaccess and still adhere to my other requirements would be:  `'/^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9.-]{8,}$/'`

Comment: No, no, no security problem whatsoever. Actually I'd love an username like that, it would be cool :-)

Comment: I made the change cause I don't want usernames to start with a "." so thanks for pointing that out  +1

Comment: I just noticed your profile. I am from Palermo - anyway - nice talking to you. Thanks for the heads up. Ciao

Comment: Don't mention it :-) (wasn't sarcastic! I'd really like such an username. I guess I have a warped sense of humour)